# Anchor does not work if set control position by code

Tags: delphi, anchor

I am using Delphi XE3.

I add two `TEdit` controls in my Form, as below:

[image]

Both have their `Anchors` set to `[akLeft, akTop, akRight]`, so that when I resize the Form, the Edits will enlarge their sizes as well.

However, if I change the position of `Edit2` in code, as follows:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Left := Edit1.Left - 10;
end;
```

Then after clicking `Button1`, I will see this:

[image]

But what I expect to see is below:

[image]

Since the right border of `Edit2` is anchored to the right border of the Form. Why does it not work as expected?

**Update**

To my understanding, the anchor means the distance between the control border and the form border is fixed, which sounds like an anchor. So right anchor means the distance between right border of edit2 and right border of form is fixed. And when changing the left border of the edit2, its width will also be changed automatically to keep the fixed distance again.

**Update2**

I reread the help document as it explained anchor as below:

"Use Anchors to ensure that a control maintains its current position relative to an edge of its parent, even if the parent is resized."

This is same as what I understand.

However, it emphasises that "Anchors is enforced only when the parent is resized.". It seems this line answer my question, since when I change Edit2.left, the form is not changed. so anchor does not work at this time.

Comment: You have answered your question in "Update2". Both sentences you refer to, dictate that it is bound to resizing of the parent. The first sentence is not *"The same as what you understand"*, or understood when you wrote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing position manually doesn't trigger anchor. Doing this by code acts the same as when design time.

What anchor property does only work when resizing its container. It doesn't work when change element positioning. What you do with left, top, height, padding, etc. acts exactly the same way when design time.

The action fired by anchor property only happen when any property related position in the container (or component) where the element is inside is fired.

What you can do is to insert a container (layout) above the elements and put all in it. When you need to change you should change the layout, not the element inside it. Edit2 should anchor left but Edit1 not.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor "right" corresponds to the width (and the anchor "bottom" to the height). Anchors in general need a parent.

But you didn't change the parent's width, hence the outcome is as expected. Maybe you can understand it better if you see anchors as relative, never absolute.

Comment: If "bottom" coresponding to height, then if no "top" anchor, what will happens? I think the anchor means the distance between the edit2 border and the form border is fixed.

Comment: That is not contradictive: no "left" anchor means `.Left` will change when the parent's width changes (provided a "right" anchor is set). And just like you cannot set "right" yourself (you can only set `.Left` and `.Width`) anchors have no effect if you touch the control, not its parent.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior. Anchors are related to the hosting component, not the component itself.

You can get what you need by writing:

```
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Edit2.Left := Edit1.Left - 10; 
  Edit2.Width := Edit2.Width + 10;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand anchor is related to the parent form. So the edit2 right border should anchor with the right border of the form, even if its left is changed, the distance between its right border and the form right border should be unchanged, that corresponding an anchor. Is that the case?

Comment: @alancc No, it isn't the case if you change the left position without changing the width as well as I shown in my answer. What works is that if you change the width of the form, then the anchor will work and change the width of the edit accordingly: the right border distance will remain constant if the form change.

Comment: @alancc Anchors only apply when a *parent* resizes. The parent knows its new dimensions and will adjust its children according to their Anchors, Margins, Padding, etc.   So, in that regard, your Edit controls will stretch accordingly as expected. But, if you move/resize a child control directly, all of those settings for that child are ignored, it will be positioned/sized where you tell it to.